# How to (permently) set keyboard mappings using setxkbmap? It gives an error

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb, setxkbmap

I am diving into custom keyboard mappings. Basically, I just want to switch the Alt_L with Ctrl_L and Alt_R with Ctrl_R (kind of like Command on MacBooks). In the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ctrl` there is already a definition for a swap of Alt_L with Ctrl_L (So adding a definition for the opposite side should be a piece of cake) called `swap_lalt_lctl`. 
However, when I type the following:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl
```

in the terminal, I receive the following error:

```
Error loading new keyboard description
```

I have already spent several hours googling and trying different things to resolve the problem, like: sudo, clearing cache, rebooting, explicitly stating machine info in command, but nothing seems to work. Strange thing is that `setxkbmap -layout us` works fine and also `setxkbmap` with other options seems to be working. 
It appears that it affects only the `ctrl:` options.

If somebody could help me out, suggest some solution paths,
I would be really grateful.

Oh, and `lsb_release -a` gives:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

---

Without taking a deep dive into xkb,
the closest I get is setting the "Ctrl is mapped to Alt, Alt to Win" option
in the Gnome-Tweaks tool.

Comment: isn't it like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662464/why-does-the-file-evdev-in-usr-share-x11-xkb-rules-not-match-with-evdev-lst) about evdev and evdev.lst? Btw it's ok in my distro ubmate20.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, to permanently keep the changes in `Xorg` it is necessary to configure it with the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` configuration files. For the keyboard configurations, the `10-keyboard.conf` file is necessary:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout"  "es"
        Option "XkbModel"   "pc104"
        Option "XkbVariant" "deadtilde,dvorak"
        Option "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
EndSection
```

In my case I use a Spanish configuration, but in your case it may vary to the necessary.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I want to permanently set my mappings, so thanks for the info. However as stated here: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/input/XKB-Config.html under 'Basic Configuration', it should also be possible to set your configuration at runtime. `setxkbmap -rules xorg -model pc104 -layout es -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"`, something like this. However this command gives me an error. Moreover!, creating a file '10-keyboard.conf' at exactly the same location and with exactly the same contents as you have does not have any effect (I've rebooted).

Comment: So the info you provide might be helpful in some later stage, but it does not seem to have any effect and I think my problem is with the error: 'Error loading new keyboard description'.